# An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method that gives me the groupID of users and then I want to get the news based on the user's GroupID.

```
public IEnumerable<News> Getnews(int GroupID)
{
    Expression<Func<News, bool>> constraint = null;
    constraint = e => e.GroupID.Equals(GroupID);
    return newsRepository.GetMany(constraint);

}
```

here I call the above method:

```
News news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);
```

and this is the error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MeetingBoard.Model.News>`' to
>   '`MeetingBoard.Model.News`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Comment: `IEnumerable<News>` is not `News`.

Comment: amazingly, I can't find an obvious exact duplicate.

Comment: I think your problem stems from the fact that the singular and plural of "News" are spelt the same. This is the same for a few other english nouns like "Sheep" for example.

Comment: If you'd wrote `var news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);` you could have saved the confusion for later.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Getnews returns a collection of news items, and your line is expecting a single news item.

You could try

```
News news = newsServices.Getnews(GroupID).FirstOrDefault();
```

or expect an ineumerable

```
IEnumerable<News> news = newsService.GetNews(GroupID);
```

Comment: or `First()`, `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()`.

Comment: Or just hide it: var news = newsService.GetNews(GroupID);

Answer (score 5):

This line is setting a variable which is defined as a single instance of News to an instance of IEnumerable :

```
News news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);
```

You want to change to

```
IEnumerable<News> = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);
```

Basically you are trying to set a collection of News to a single reference of News.

Answer (score 4):

`Getnews` returns an `IEnumerable<News>` (i.e. multiple News) and you are trying to assign it to `News news` (i.e. a single News item). That doesn't work.

There are two possibilities, depending on what you want to do.

If you want to use all the news, change `News news` to `IEnumerable<News>`:

```
IEnumerable<News> news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);
```

If you want to use only a single news, use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
News news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Depending on what you expect, you also could use one of the following:

- `First()`: You expect `Getnews` to always return at least one news. This will throw an exception if no news are returned.
- `Single()`: You expect `Getnews` to always return exactly one news. This will throw an exception if more than one or zero news are returned.
- `SingleOrDefault()`: You expect zero or one news to be returned. This will throw an exception if more than one news are returned.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you want

```
IEnumerable<News> news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID);
```

or maybe something like:

```
News news = newsService.Getnews(GroupID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

`return newsRepository.GetMany(constraint);` returns an `IEnumerable<News>`, you should do:

```
 return newsRepository.GetMany(constraint).FirstOrDefault();
```

return the first `News` if it is found in `newRepository`, null otherwise

Answer (score 0):

An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
I was facing same problem in my C# code. I was writing code in VS.
I checked full code, and I get reason behind this error.
I missed 'I' in my explicit Interface name.

**Picture with Error**

[image: Picture with Error]

**Error Solution**

[image: Error Solution]