# How to get IEnumerable to have the right type

Tags: c#, ienumerable

So I have a program that is supposed to take a bunch of values, store them in a "projects" object inside a function, which is called from this block of code:

```
    public IEnumerable<ProjectAll> GetAllProjects()
    {
        var project = pullAllProjects();
        return project;
    }
```

The error is at return *project*, and reads:

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProjectsApp.Models.Project' 
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectsApp.Models.ProjectAll>'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

So, I found this on StackOverflow:
[An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333557/an-explicit-conversion-exists-are-you-missing-a-cast)

But when I followed those instructions...

```
            IEnumerable <Project> project = new Project();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                project.Id = (int)rdr["project_id"];
                project.Name = (string)rdr["project_name"];
                project.Title = (string)rdr["project_title"];
                project.Network = (int)rdr["main_network"];
                project.Start = (DateTime)rdr["project_start"];
            }
            return project;
```

I got an error on each of the variables(Id, Name, ect).

```
Error   4   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectsApp.Models.Project>' 
does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a 
first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectsApp.Models.Project>' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It seemed to work for the person at the StackOverflow link, what's different about the way I'm doing it?

Let me know if I need to add more information, thanks in advance!

Comment: give some more information how your ProjectAll and Project class look like. What you return from pullAllProjects();

Comment: What is indicated in your PullAllProjects()?

Comment: You're naming your variables/functions incorrectly and confusing yourself. Use a plural noun for `IEnumerable`s of things. Use a singular noun for single instances. An `IEnumerable<Project>` variable should not be named `project`, and you can't assign a single instance of a `Project` to a variable that is supposed to hold an `IEnumerable` of them.

Comment: Are you sure you know what the IEnumerable interface represents, and how you're supposed to use it?

Comment: Look at the return type for `pullAllProjects()`.  The error explanation would suggest that it's returning `ProjectsApp.Models.Project` instead of an IEnumerable collection of `ProjectsApp.Models.ProjectAll`.

Comment: As other people have stated, can you post the function `pullAllProjects()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerable<Project>` cannot be assigned from `Project`. Correct way to do that:

```
public IEnumrable<Project> pullAllProjects
{
    .
    .
    .
    var projects = new List<Project>();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        projects.Add(new Project 
        {
            Id = (int)rdr["project_id"];
            Name = (string)rdr["project_name"];
            Title = (string)rdr["project_title"];
            Network = (int)rdr["main_network"];
            Start = (DateTime)rdr["project_start"];
         });
    }
    return projects;
}
```

Comment: What's with the return project.AsEnumerable()? Shouldn't it just be return projects.

Comment: Yes if signature of returning method is IEnumerable<..., `AsEnumerable()` can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the statement "IEnumerable  project = new Project();" you're trying to initialize an IEnumerable object with a Project object. An IEnumerable has to be initialized with an object that implements IEnumerable. Project isn't an enumerable; there's no way to iterate through it. In this case, you could use one of the more-commonly-used IEnumerables in C#, List, like so:

```
List<Project> projects = new List<Project>();
```

This creates and initializes an empty collection of Project objects.

Then, you add Project objects to the List. If you already know the objects you'd like to include in the List, you could construct it like so:

```
List<Project> projects = new List<Project> { a, b, c, ... };
```

where all items contained within the brackets are Project items.

As you should be doing it, you can add them the same way you've specified in your code:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    project.Id = (int)rdr["project_id"];
    project.Name = (string)rdr["project_name"];
    project.Title = (string)rdr["project_title"];
    project.Network = (int)rdr["main_network"];
    project.Start = (DateTime)rdr["project_start"];
 }
```